# Representing graph as a search tree

Tags: graphs, data-structures, search-trees

How do I convert a graph to a search tree? Here's the question-
[image]

The problem is that I don't know how to represent interconnections in a graph on a tree. In the diagram A is connected to D, and same goes for B and E, C and F. But in tree I think no interconnections should be there between sibling nodes. ***So how do I represent a search tree? It would be helpful if someone can also tell me what's the difference between a tree and a search tree.***

I didn't know how to do it so I drew a minimum spanning tree instead-
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Algorithms](http://algorithmics.lsi.upc.edu/docs/Dasgupta-Papadimitriou-Vazirani.pdf) by Dasgupta, Papadimitriou and Vazirani represents a traversal tree as a tree rooted in the first vertex of the traversal search, with solid edges corresponding to edges crossed during the traversal, and dashed or dotted edges corresponding to remaining edges.

See page 92 of the pdf for an example.

There are interesting properties doing as such:

- the pre-order traversal of the tree is the same as the order of the traversal of the graph;
- the post-order traversal of a DFS tree in a directed acyclic graph results in a reverse topological order.

As for your last question, the main difference between a tree and a search tree is that the search tree is rooted.